# Androidx NotificationCompat vs Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a mobile application which requires a push notification to notify the user when a certain condition is met. I am new to this and I discovered multiple ways to implement a push notification.

However, I am unsure of which one is best to be implemented. I am new to mobile app development so I am unsure of how to differ both of them.

From my understanding, androidx NotificationCompat is easier to be used but my SV suggests me to use Firebase Cloud Messaging instead.

Comment: `NotificationCompat` is how you show notification in android, FCM is the medium by which notification data reaches to the device. Furthermore, from backend, if you pass data in `data` key in FCM Payload, you've to use `NotificationCompat` to manually show the notification to the user, this gives you the power of customization of notifications and handling the extra data keys you receive with the notification payload. If you use `notification` key, FCM displays a generic notification by itself without you controlling the design of notification, you can still pass data with this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

- `NotificationCompat` is the helper class for the developer to access in `android.app.Notification`.
- `Firebase Cloud Message(FCM)` is a cross-platform messaging solution that lets you reliably send messages at no cost.

I can't help you make a final decision, I just list the positive and negative options of them, hope can help you.

**For FCM**

1. To notify the end-user of the new message which you want them to know(eg. bouns/upgrade, even though the cycling message at 18:30 every day, etc).
2. Help the developer to track the lifecycle of the notification(how many were opened? how many were canceled, etc..)
3. Help the developer to Customize the Notification Styles, and can also preview them in the console of the FCM.
4. Can also implement your own background and send your customized message to the background center of the FCM with `XMPP`
5. Can also send message to the part of the user

   - With some topic(eg: send message to the user who enters some page or use some function)
   - With some age(eg: send message to the user who ages between 29 and 25 years old)

**For NotificationCompact**

- use for local, hard control from your backend.
- others...

Comment: wow thank you @caopeng! okay now I have a brief idea why to implement FCM. Btw, is websocket similar to FCM?